# How to test nested promises setState inside a fetch call in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, promise, jestjs, fetch, enzyme

I've seen similar solutions on stack overflow but they usually involved moving the fetch call into it's own function and calling it inside componentDidMount. But how would I go about testing a fetch call inside componentDidMount that sets the state using jest/enzyme? The data retrieved from the api call can be any arbitrary value..

Here is my code for componentDidMount

```
 async componentDidMount() {
     await fetch(
       "api call",
       {
         method: "GET",
       }
     )
       .then((res) => res.json())
       .then(
         (result) => {
           const jsonData = JSON.parse(result);
           this.setState({
             modalOpen: "",
             eventNameState: jsonData.eventNameState,
             event: jsonData.event,
             name: jsonData.eventNameState,
      });
    },
    (error) => {
      this.setState({ error });
    }
  );
}
```

I've tried using this code to test it but always get a _nock.default is not a function error

```
 beforeAll(() => {
     nock(
       "api call"
     ).reply(200, {
       eventNameState: "TEST",
     });
   });

   it("Component fetches data from API", async (done) => {
     const root = shallow(<EventState />);
     let componentState = {};
     await waitUntil(() => root.state("eventNameState") !== null);
     expect(componentState).toEqual("TEST");
   });
 });
```

Comment: What is `const spy - jest`?

Comment: sorry thats a typo